# Converting variable to time (mm ss)

Tags: c#, audio

I am trying to convert a variable `audio.Duration` in C# to a time displaying string. Basically, `audio` is a DirectX audio instance loaded using an open file dialog. I want to be able to display the duration at the end of a progress bar, inside a label, however `DurationLabel = audio.Duration.ToString();` gives me silly values like `350.2739201`.

How can I convert it so it displays the text as `mm:ss:(milliseconds)` instead?

Comment: do you mean `System.Windows.Duration` structure used mainly in `WPF`?

Comment: No, more like `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Audio.Duration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio.Duration is a double
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb324228(v=vs.85).aspx

Try this

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(audio.Duration);

DurationLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", 
                    (int)time.TotalHours,
                    time.Minutes,
                    time.Seconds);
```

Comment: How can I get it into `DurationLabel.Text` instead of `Console.WriteLine` ?

Comment: String.Format returns a string .. so just assign to your label text property. Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`DurationLabel.Text =TimeSpan.FromSeconds(audio.Duration).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");`

Comment: Damith, nice one liner :)